# Suppose that $S$ is a bounded, infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ having exactly one limit point $x_{0}$.

Tags: analysis

Prove that, for any $\varepsilon>0$, the neighborhood ${N}'(x_{0}; \varepsilon )$ contains all but finitely many of the points of $S$.

I don't understand what the problem means. Problem says $S$ is an infinite set, and  ${N}'(x_{0}; \varepsilon )$ contains "all but finitely many" of the points of $S$. I think it is a contradiction. Is this problem incorrect? If so, please correct and solve it.

For example, $S=\left\{\frac{1}{n} : n\in \mathbb{N} \right\}$, then $S$ is a bounded and infinite set and having exactly one limit point $x_{0}=0$. What is the next step?

Comment: How many points of your set would $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ not contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there are infinitely many points of $S$ which do not belong to $N'(x_0,\epsilon)$. Then these points have  a limit point $x_1$. But any limit point of these points is also a limit ponit of $S$ so we must have $x_0=x_1$. But then infinitely many of these points would be in $N'(x_0,\epsilon)$. This is a contradiction since none of these poinst beloing to $N'(x_0,\epsilon)$!